# Adding custom OAuth to Xenforo 1.5

Tags: php, oauth, xenforo

We need the ability to log in to Xenforo 1.5 using our own OAuth which is developed already. I didn't find any proper documentation on how to do that. Any help much appreciated.
I know they have options to use FB, Google and Twitter. There should be a way to add custom connected accounts too.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so there's no documentation on that for Xenforo 1.5
What I did is just downloaded an add-on that does it for some social networks and looking at the code to see how it's done.